# Изменение фона Button через стили

Tags: android

Есть некая форма, в ней кнопка "отправить". Изначально кнопка неактивная (серая), по мере заполнения формы в определённый момент кнопка активируется (должен меняться цвет фона и текста).

Я создал два стиля

```
<style name="button">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorButtonBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorButtonCaption</item>
</style>
<style name="button.disabled" parent="button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorButtonBackgroundDisabled</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorButtonCaptionDisabled</item>
</style>
```

Сама кнопка изначально неактивная:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    style="@style/button.disabled"
    android:text="@string/login_submit"
    ...
/>
```

Отображается, как надо.
Затем, я проверяю заполненность формы и ставлю стиль кнопки.
Как я нагуглил нужно использовать `setTextApperance()`:

```
val style = if (enabled) R.style.button else R.style.button_disabled
if (SDK_INT >= 23) {
    submit.setTextAppearance(style)
} else {
    submit.setTextAppearance(context, style)
}
```

Однако, цвет текста меняется, а вот цвет фона нет.
Аналогично, если изначально задать "активную" тему.
Цвета будут нужные, но при переключении в "неактивную" поменятся только цвет текста.
Проверка показала, что также меняются другие параметры, связанные именно с текстом (размер, например), но не с самим блоком (margin и т.п)

На мысли наводит название метода `setTextAppearance`, что работает он только с текстом.
Но я не вижу никаких других подобных методов для того, чтобы применить всю тему.

Comment: `setTextAppearance`  используется чтобы изменить атрибуты, связанные с **текстом**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете помимо `setTextAppearance` так же менять `background` у кнопки.

Лучшим вариантом будет создать `selector` который среагирует на состояние кнопки

**res/drawable/my_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground" />
  <item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:background="@color/colorButtonCaptionDisabled" />
</selector>
```

Поставить его фоном для кнопки `android:background="@drawable/my_button"` и управлять состоянием кнопки `submit.setEnabled(false/true);`

Или использовать библиотеку [paris](https://github.com/airbnb/paris)

```
Paris.style(submit).apply(R.style.MyStyle);//java
submit.style(R.style.MyStyle)//kotlin
```

Comment: Спасибо. То есть нет способов просто динамически применить стили к элементу?